# Show a confirm dialog from ORM methods

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to perform some checking in the ORM write method and show a confirm dialog with yes/no choices to ask confirmation.
If the user click yes, then the record will be saved. Otherwise, the dialog would just be closed.
I tried using exception raising  but I don't know how to get which button the user clicked. Moreover, raising an exception implies that the method execution stops which is not what I want.

I also tried by creating a wizard in order to have a custom confirm dialog. But to display that wizard, a dict populated with special values (such as the id of the wizard view) has to be returned. Obviously, I can't return that dict from ORM method such as write.
How can I achieve this ?
 What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add `confirm` attribute to the XML file defining the button that triggers the ORM method in question just like this `<button name="orm_write" type="object" confirm="Are you sure to ...?"/>`.

Comment: Not really because the confirm dialog should be displayed following a condition. If I put a confirm attribute in the xml button it will be displayed unconditionally.